# How to Return Single row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When i am check the Multi-line function

```
select * from calculation('2')
```

Error:

Hi after google i came to know that it's returning two rows(multiple rows) but no idea how to slove this can any give me suggestion please

```
enter code here

 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[calculation]
(@AgentID int)
 RETURNS @CustomerPosition TABLE 
(
-- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
DayAmount      Decimal   Not NULL,
MonthAmount    Decimal   NOT NULL,
YearAmount     Decimal   NOT NULL,
Position        INT      NOT NULL

)
AS
BEGIN
-- Fill the table variable with the rows for your result set
INSERT Into @CustomerPosition(DayAmount,MonthAmount,YearAmount,Position)

 Declare @DayAmount as Decimal
  set @DayAmount = (select sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperday from 
 tblcollections  
where AgentID=@AgentID and datepart(dd,Date_Time)= DATEPART(DD,GETDATE())
group by AgentID)





--SET NOCOUNT ON
 DECLARE @MonthStartDate As datetime
 DECLARE @MonthEndDate As datetime
 DECLARE @today datetime
 set @today = convert(varchar(12) , getdate() , 101) 

  SET @MonthStartDate = @today
   Declare @MonthAmount as Decimal
    set @MonthAmount = (select  sum(AmountRecevied)as Totoalamountperday from 
tblcollections  
where AgentID=@AgentID and Date_Time between   dateadd(dd,-  datepart(dd,@MonthStartDate),@MonthStartDate+1) and  dateadd(dd,-1,dateadd(mm,+1,@MonthStartDate))
           group by AgentID)



Declare @YearAmount as Decimal
    set @YearAmount=(select sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountpermonth  from 
tblcollections  
where AgentID=@AgentID  and datepart(YYYY,Date_Time) =YEAR(GETDATE())
group by AgentID)

     Declare @Position as Decimal
    set @Position =  (select [RowNumber] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AgentID DESC) from 
    tblcollections  
where AgentID=@AgentID
group by AgentID
)


RETURN 
 END
```

Comment: and it's not returing data also

Comment: what is datepart(dd,Date_Time)= Isdate(GETDATE()) supposed to mean ? Isdate(GETDATE()) always equals 1 and datepart(dd,Date_Time) evaluates to 1..31 (if it runs at all, what is date_time?)

Comment: also you declared \@MonthStartDate, \@MonthEndDate but aasigned no values to them, so they are null, no suprise the code returns no data

Comment: no i modified but still not return data

Comment: does this code (I mean alter not function call) run at all?

Comment: yes command success and return empty columns

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52299/discussion-between-avb-and-sandeep)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ...
```